# How do I create "Rim Lighting" in macro photography?

Tags: lighting, macro, strobist

I enjoy macro photography and have heard of using "Rim Lighting" for higher contrast. How do I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get a rim light by placing the light behind your subject, but it's more used in portrait photography than in macro ([see example](http://www.flickr.com/photos/preciouskhyatt/3151891639/)). But I guess it can work, if you make your light small enough to fit behind what you're shooting.

Comment: Just a thought - isn't the light source in your example behind and above the subject? If so, you needn't use a small light source, just place it high enough so it's out of shot, no?

Comment: I think it's hidden behind the model in the example. It probably wouldn't make much difference if it was above and just out of frame, but if you put it significantly higher then highlights will look different -- it won't be just rim, but larger area -- something similar to highlights in http://www.flickr.com/photos/aknacer/3320219356/. But the main difference would be practical: you'd have to work around light stand that would be visible in picture, and shade the camera lens to prevent loss of contrast. Both of these things are taken care of when you stick the flash behind his head.